# Too many arguments in generalized version of fold function for BST

Tags: haskell, binary-search-tree, fold

Running ***fold (+) 0 sample*** gives me an error about (+) being applied to too many arguments. Why?

```
data(Ord a, Show a, Read  a) => BST a = Void | Node {
    val :: a,
    left, right :: BST a
} deriving (Eq,  Ord,  Read,  Show)

sample = Node 5 (Node 3 Void Void) (Node 10 Void Void)

fold :: (Read a, Show a, Ord a) => (a -> b -> b ->  b) -> b -> BST a -> b
fold _ z Void         = z
fold f z (Node x l r) = f x (fold f z l) (fold f z r)
```

> ```
> Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a = a -> a
> Probable cause: `+' is applied to too many arguments
> In the first argument of `fold'', namely `(+)'
> In the expression: fold' (+) 0 sample
> ```

See also: [fold](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Fold)

Comment: You might want to check out making your type an instance of [Foldable](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Foldable.html#t:Foldable) and [Traversable](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Traversable.html#t:Traversable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `fold` requires a function of type `a -> b -> b ->  b` as its first parameter, that is a function that takes three arguments. `(+)` on the other hand only takes two arguments.

If `fold` should be changed or if you need call it with a different function depends on what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: ok, `fold (\x y z -> x+y+z) 0 sample` works and sums all elements of the BST. However, while foldr and foldl defined in Haskell are quite simple to understand, I can't imagine how BST fold function is actually applying to the tree elements. I mean the order, just like the link to Haskell wiki in first post.

Comment: Gremo, when you fold in a tree, you have three pieces of information: the value you got from folding the left subtree, the value you got from folding the right subtree, and the value that lives in this particular node.  That's different from a list, because lists don't branch out as trees do, so they just have the current value and the computed value from the rest of the list.  The type signature of a fold depends on the type you are folding over.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is you are applying the function to 3 arguments. The first parameter in the type signature says it all.

```
fold :: (a -> b -> b -> b) -> b -> BST a -> b
fold f z (Node x l r) = f x (fold f z l) (fold f z r)
```

(+) only takes 2 arguments, but when you pass it in, it tries to evaluate this:

```
(+) x (fold (+) z l) (fold (+) z r) -- 3 arguments! =P
```

You probably want to fold with a binary function (a -> a -> a). Suppose you want to use (+). You want the result to be like this:

```
fold f z (Node x l r) = x + (fold f z l) + (fold f z r)
```

From there it's easy to generalize: just replace `+` with an infixed `f`

```
fold f z (Node x l r) :: (a -> a -> a) -> a -> BST a -> a
fold f z (Node x l r) = x `f` (fold f z l) `f` (fold f z r)
```